# How can I solve this "SyntaxError: invalid synta"?

Tags: python3, pip

```
$ pip3 install PyFFTW3

Collecting PyFFTW3
  Using cached PyFFTW3-0.2.1.tar.gz (25 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o6a_mdhw/PyFFTW3/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o6a_mdhw/PyFFTW3/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-o6a_mdhw/PyFFTW3/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o6a_mdhw/PyFFTW3/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o6a_mdhw/PyFFTW3/setup.py", line 81
        print "build %s from template %s" %(outfile, tmplfile)
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install a python2 package with pip3 - see for example [Installation does not work on Python 3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyfftw/+bug/1101945)

Comment: Please note that PyFFTW is packaged for both Python 2 and Python 3 in the [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=PyFFTW). You are trying to build library from [2010 year](https://pypi.org/project/PyFFTW3/#history). What are your Ubuntu version and final idea?

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic wrapper around FFTW - Python 3 (*python3-pyfftw*) can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyfftw
```